# sensor_msgs/LaserScan.msg ==> range_max should be discarded

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have been dealing with **slam_gmapping** package and I have reached good results so far.(I created my map by the package) But I have a question about sensor_msgs/LaserScan.msg specifically. For describing my problem a lot faster, I want you to look at the picture below. In the picture, you can see my /scan topic and a view of Rviz. When you look at the /scan topic, I selected some of those **ranges** data where start off with the value of 65.53399. You can clearly see the relevant points in the Rviz screen too since they are far away from average measurements. As I pass such scan data into **slam_gmapping** package, the map is not created well.

I believe that the value of 65.53399 in the /scan topic is used for failed scan data or something like that. I should not take these measurements account in the context of creating a map. But how? In the **LaserScan.msg** there is an explanation goes like that:

> float32[] ranges         # range data
> [m] (Note: values < range_min or >
> range_max should be discarded)

What I should understand of discarding data in the **ranges** std::vector? What value I should give for such failed/max data instead of leaving them as they are? Any idea or useful links? Thank you all in advance!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388471/sensor_msgs/laserscan.msg-==%3E-range_max-should-be-discarded/) by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is covered by [REP-117: Informational Distance Measurements](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html).

Specifically (I've changed the formatting slightly):

> #### Specification
>
> For any sensor measurement that reports physical distance (see [Range](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html), [LaserScan](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html), [PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)), **three special conditions will be well-defined**. These readings shall be:
>
> 1. detection too close to determine true distance but not cause an erroneous measurement
> 2. an erroneous measurement that has no useful physical quantification; and
> 3. no information within the useful range of the sensor but likely no object within range.
>
> **Detections that are too close to the sensor to quantify shall be represented by -Inf. Erroneous detections shall be represented by quiet (non-signaling) NaNs. Finally, out of range detections will be represented by +Inf**.

I would suggest you update your lidar driver to follow this convention.

Consumers should then be able to correctly interpret your `LaserScan`s.

> I write the scan program by myself. I don't use any launch file or library.

this confuses me a little. The screenshot you show seems to imply you're using a Hokuyo scanner. Those have traditionally been very well supported in ROS, and the drivers should already conform to REP-117. Can you not use those?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2021-10-12**:
Hi gvdhoorn, thank you for your reply. I will work on the links you shared to improve my program. I appreciate.

I use this sensor(HOKUYO UAM-05LP). I will check some hokuyo laser scanner libraries/drivers such as http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node in order to check I can use these drivers or not for my sensor. If I can use them properly, I'd switch to use them quickly instead of my own program.

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2021-10-13**:
Hi all, I did an amendment according to this documentation([REP-117: Informational Distance Measurements](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html)) in my program. I added a if-statement like below. This solved my problem, I am able to use this scan_data to create a quality map with **slam_gmapping** package now. I guess, **slam_gmapping** package recognizes the value of -Inf,+Inf, and NaNs in the **ranges** vector in the /scan_topic. And handles all data by itself according to SLAM algorithm that it uses.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1081; i++)
{
   float scan_item = scan_data[i] /1000.0  ;  
   if(scan_item == 65.53399658203125)
       laser_example.ranges.push_back( +INFINITY) ; 
   else
       laser_example.ranges.push_back( scan_item) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually your lidar launch file will have a `range_max` parameter. You can keep it to whatever your desired value is.
If the `range_max` parameter is not in your launch file, try running your lidar launch file and doing `rosparam list` to see if there is a range related parameter.

As I can see in the image you have posted, your `range_max` is set to 100.

You can just modify it directly in your launch file.

> float32[] ranges # range data [m]
> (Note: values < range_min or >
> range_max should be discarded)

It means that any distance value coming from the lidar that is less than your desired `range_min` or distance value more than your desired `range_max` will be either shown as 0 or removed from the list of your distance array.

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2021-10-12**:
Hi siddharthcb, thank you for your reply. I write the scan program by myself. I don't use any launch file or library. In short, I publish what I got from the sensor(raw data). And the sensor gives these broken values occasionally.

If I assign 0(zero) for failed scan in the /scan topic; **slam_gmapping** will suppose that this specific angle in the map is occupied while we don't know whether this specific angle is occupied or not in reality. That's why I found illogical to assign 0 for unknown angles. Alternatively, if I remove the 65.53399 values in **ranges** vector; then **my scan.ranges.size()** will change and cause that I can't express 270 degree(angle_max-angle_min) with an array with 1081 elements(sensor resolution for 270 degree) no more. Because I remove some amount of measurements out of **ranges** vector. What **slam_gmapping** package expect me to give for such situations?

**Comment by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on 2021-10-12**:
what is the maximum range you want your lidar to read?
It has to be occupied because it corresponds to some angle.
Btw, you can always set the max_range in your publishing node, suppose you do not want anything more than 50, just set

```
data.range_max = 50
pub.publish(data)
```